# Trying to create the bootstrap carousel with press tab and enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Trying to create the bootstrap carousel with tab key press support. I just used this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-carousel-with-text blog.

Trying to add tab and press key feature. If the end user can press tab and enter key it should point to the left and right arrow and below carousel-indicators as well and then navigate to the next slider.

Please suggest me how to add the feature in it.

Comment: Please include what you have tried yourself

Comment: I have used this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-carousel-with-text carousel style and elements. But couldn't navigate the left and right arrows If I press the tab key. How can I add this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add key listeners as given below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38) { // left nav key pressed
            // code to load prev slide
        } else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // right nav key pressed
            // code to load next slide
        }
    });

});
```

You can find all key codes here: http://keycode.info/

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated. You should be using `e.key` or `e.code` instead, which are supported in all major browsers. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev